# How to open new tab in browser using python and send POST data?

Tags: python, http, post, python-webbrowser

I am using Python's `webbrowser` module and I think it only supports opening a new tab in my browser. I like to send data using POST request using python and open that in my browser. Is there any library for that?

Comment: Have you tried selenium?

Comment: Yes, you can use Selenium for opening the browser and then loading the relevant site. After that, you can send POST request using 'request' library in Python.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
import os
url = "google.com"
os.system('start chrome ' + url)
```

for open new tab
and you can use

```
import requests
request.post(url,json/data)
```

for post request

Comment: What about the `POST`? I want to send parameter and data

Comment: the last code, you can send the post request and then open the browser